# EF: Proper one-to-zero/one relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have `User` which may have zero or one `Profile`. 
From the code perspective it should be more convenient if I can access `Profile` from `User` (because I will access User information more often then its profile), but this conflicts with EF Code First:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This, put in DbContext, will create tables, where I cannot create `User` without having `Profile` created before => bad, as the `User` is obvious principle.
The easiest (for stupid I) solution is obvious:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me more expected behaviour of databases.

But... I have feeling that this solution is not best approach. For example I'm not able to access all Users through all Profiles using lazy loading.
So the question is "How to properly setup one-to-zero/one relationship (via DataAnnotation and FluentAPI)?"
In other words "How to properly setup "one `User` - to - zero/one `Profile`" relationship?"

Maybe I think of it totally wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Drauka. His proposal led me to the solution:

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
class Profile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

So the trick is done by `Required` which marks that the entity, where it is defined, is dependent while the other one is principal. And it saves one collumn in both tables (for foreign key id).

Just one problem remained: how to ensure `Profile` is deleted in cascade when deleting `User`?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. How to enable cascade on delete. It seems like there is no data annotation that will enforce this, and you will have to use the fluent api instead.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Added cascade on delete to the solution.

Try this

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(x => x.Profile).WithRequired(x => x.User).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work as it do not recognize Principal and Dependant role, which is the key to the solution - already add it. But still thanks - that was the kick I needed :-)

Comment: @Zoka My solution does work as I'm running a working example locally. It's however important to override the OnModelCreating as shown.
Further I have updated the solution to handle the cascade delete.
I'd appreciate that you tried it again as you have written my solution doesn't work which is simply not true and I don't wan't my name associated with such.

Comment: OK, you are right - it works. Problem is on my side, where my scenario is much more complicated with some inheritance. When I try it with these simple classes it works. Theerefore please accept my apologize.

Comment: @zoka No worries .. just wanted to clarify if someone else reads the solution and thinks it's not working.